# Variable defined in while loop cannot be defined

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

I have a while loop like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        h = int(raw_input("Please Enter your altitude in metres > "))
        if h > 0 and h < 11000:
            phase = 'Troposphere'
            break
    except ValueError:
            print 'Your entered value contained letters or punctuation. Please enter a numerical value.'
```

and later I want to use the values for `h` and `phase` but my IDE is telling me it cannot be defined. The values are being used in a calculation and the phase is printed.

Comment: Do you want to store all the 'h'/phase values while looping, or just the last one ?

Comment: What is the exception you see in IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your variables outside the while block so they can be used outside such block:

```
h = 0
phase = 0
while True:
    try:
        h = int(raw_input("Please Enter your altitude in metres > "))
        if h > 0 and h < 11000:
            phase = 'Troposphere'
            break
    except ValueError:
            print 'Your entered value contained letters or punctuation. Please enter a numerical value.'
```

Comment: phase should be a string ''.

Comment: The execution will not pass the loop unless _h_ is defined

Comment: Python is weak typed so phase can be initialized with a value of any type.

Comment: I think you  mean [dynamically typed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11328980/3155195)

Comment: What I meant is that there's mo need to define _h_ before the loop - it is redundant

Comment: @volcano Yes, it is. Maybe a bug in the IDE?