# Python local variables statically determined?

Tags: python, static

Python tutorial says that (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

> In fact, local variables are already determined statically.

How to understand this? Based on what I knew *static* means that the type of a variable is determined at compile time. But it is not true considering for example

```
x = 1
x = 'str'
```

where the variable x is dynamically bound to objects of type int or string at runtime.

Reference: [Is Python strongly typed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed)

Comment: there is no variables in `Python`: just names and objects

Comment: [this great post](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) can give you an explanation of what is going on

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: From that post: "Myth: Python has no variables." Variables don't have to work like C variables to use the name. You might prefer the "name" name, but saying Python doesn't have variables is wrong.

Comment: @user2357112: ok, `Python` has no variables like most people used to think of them

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: thx for the link, I've just read it through, but apart from what user2357112 has pointed out (Python does have variables) there seems nothing new in there, and I think I offer a much clearer description in my question (from the aspect of variable and object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, consider the error produced by the following code.

```
x = 1

def function():
    y = x + 1
    x = 3

function()
```

This will produce an error like "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment" because it is determined that `x` is a local variable in `function` so it should be found in the local scope, negating the global definition.

Comment: Interesting code snippet. I think the error arises from name collision in the same scope. In `x = x + 1`, the lhs x causes a new local variable x to be created in this local scope. And as a result, the rls x would refer to this local x, instead of searching all the way to the global scope.

Comment: @swang try it with just `x + 1` without assignment then

Answer (score 2):

Their *existence*, and whether a variable lookup is local or global, is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a statement in that document too.

> if not declared nonlocal, those variables are read-only (an attempt
> to write to such a variable will simply create a new local variable in
> the innermost scope, leaving the identically named outer variable
> unchanged).

In Jared Goguen's code, clause `x = 3` will let Python see `x` as local during compile.