# Strong typed python3.7 - return type and params are not failed

Tags: python-3.7

I don't quite understand why this is not failing:

```
def hello(name: str) -> int:
    ending:int = '!!!'
    return f'Hello {name} {ending}'

print(hello('John')) # Hello John !!!
```

And if there is already possibility to strong type python?

Comment: Why would it fail? Type *hints* are just hints. They have no effect during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is explained in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals) by Guido himself:

> It should also be emphasized that **Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention**.

So the answer is NO. Type hints are only hints. They help to indicate what type of data a variable or function **should/may** contain/returns/etc. It wasn't designed to transform Python into a statically typed language.

Comment: Strong typing is not the same as static typing, though. Python does raise runtime type errors unlike weakly typed languages such as javascript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed?rq=1

Comment: I there possiblity though that could raise those error (like parameter)? `python3.7 --strong`?

Comment: @HåkenLid I just fixed my answer. Thanks !

Comment: @Meroz: No, there's no runtime enforcement of type hints. You have to use a type checker such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). It would probably be possible to create a runtime type checker which uses type hints, but that would have a performance cost. The PyCharm IDE uses the type hints for code linting, and you can also configure other editors to use mypy for the same.

Comment: Performance cost only on running on development mode, on production would be without `--check-types` parameter. I use VS Code, do you know any extentions for it?

Comment: I can `pip3 install mypy` and `mypy file.py`, and it will show me where I have errors with types.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comment it is nice to use `mypy myproject.py` to run it before project/code run. Then you could verify data types structure and correct flow.