# Typehinting decorators that alter function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, pyright

I'm creating a decorator, and I'd like the `typehint` to be preserved. However, I need to alter the return type a little bit. The [Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#declaring-decorators) contain information on how to do this if your decorated function signature is the same as the original one, but I'm not sure how to do this if the return type is altered.

As an example, here is my original function:

```py
async def simple_func(a: int) -> int:
    'Simple sleeper function to test calling mechanics'
    return a + 1
```

It has the signature `(int) -> Awaitable[int]`.

Here is how I use it:

```py
    t_wrap = make_sync(simple_func)
    _ = get_event_loop()
    assert t_wrap(4) == 5
```

When I look at the type of `t_wrap` using pyright or a similar tool in my editor, it is `(*args, **kwargs) -> int`, rather than `(int) -> int`.

My decorator function is as follows:

```py
from functools import wraps
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
R = TypeVar('R')

def make_sync(fn: Callable[..., Awaitable[R]]) -> Callable[..., R]:
    @wraps(fn)
    def sync_version_of_function(*args, **kwargs):
        stuff stuff stuff
        r = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        stuff stuff stuff
    return sync_version_of_function
```

What I'm missing is how to deal with the `...` - I'd like to define a `TypeVar` `A` to represent the list of arguments, but I can't figure out how to approach that.

Comment: Last I checked mypy, at least, didn't support this.

Comment: Thanks! Is that because mypi hasn't implemented it, or because typehints isn't expressive enough?

Comment: Type hints are hints - in the end, Python is not a strongly typed language and the information simply isn't available to be preserved. Your `sync_version_of_function` has a clearly defined signature and that's the signature you get, since you could pass any type of function into the decorator.

Comment: @Grismar python *is* a strongly typed language, it is *dynamically* typed rather than *statically typed*. There are third-party libraries that provide static type checking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - thanks for the clarification, you're absolutely right, brain fart on my part, I wanted to say "not statically typed". If OP is curious what it means, this has a good answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed

Comment: @Gordon so, yes, I don't think this was addressed in any of the PEPs that have defined how type hints will work. Of course, another PEP could come out and define this. [Here's](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3157) an informative issue on the state of things. Indeed, someone in that thread pointed to a [new PEP](https://github.com/python/peps/pull/1259) that is proposing just something like this. But basically, I don't think there is any support currently.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - thanks! The current pep in master can be found here: https://github.com/mrkmndz/peps/blob/master/pep-0612.rst - and the example it uses is almost identical to the one that I have, but in reverse (they are adding an Awaitable, rather than stripping it away). If you write this up as the answer, I'll mark it!