# MacOS VSCode Python Setup

Tags: python

When I run anything other than your print("Hello, World") the terminal prints the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/juliuseners/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/juliuseners/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/juliuseners/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/Users/juliuseners/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/Users/juliuseners/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/Users/juliuseners/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.16.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/juliuseners/pythondir/Chapter 1.py", line 14, in <module>
    if dis>0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'
```

I fail to solve the problem, has anyone ran into this before?

Tried manually changing PATH using homebrews recommendations but somehow I cannot get this to work.

EDIT:
Im adding the code I'm attempting to run below:

```
import math
#The quadratic is luckily solved for all coefficients a,b,c except for a=0: this diqualifies the equation as quadratic. 
#I write the function based on following formula: x=(-b+/-sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/2a

a=input("Enter a: ")
b=input("Enter b: ")
c=input("Enter c: ")

def findmyroots(a,b,c):
   dis=b*b-4*a*c
   sqrtdis=math.sqrt(abs(dis))
if dis>0:
    print("The roots are:")
    print((-b+sqrtdis)/(2*a))
    print((-b-sqrtdis)/(2*a))
elif dis==0:
    print("The roots are:")
    print((-b)/(2*a))
else:
    print("Roots are lateral")

if a==0:
    print("Write a real quadratic please..")
else:1
    findmyroots(a,b,c)
```

Comment: can you give an example of what are you trying?

Comment: Just trying to write a program that solves quadratic equations.

Comment: What is `dis` variable ?

Comment: The traceback is actually showing what you are running and it's not `print("Hello, World")`. So, show us your code!

Comment: You need to be more specific.. Try to reproduce your error with a simple example.

Comment: Your code has an error in it: `if dis>0:` the error message is pretty clear. What exactly are you asking? This seems to have nothing to do with VSCode

Comment: I wrote a comment, but I think my conclusion was incorrect (about what is causing this issue). Instead, your `if` blocks need to be indented to be inside of your function.

Comment: 1. Your code has a nesting problem: if dis > 0 (and subsequent lines) is not a part of a findmyroots function. Thus, dis is looked up in global context. 2. Either VSCode or one of the plugins you installed has auto-import featue, and imports dis function from dis module (equivalent to `from dis import dis`)

Comment: @BeRT2me The code is wrong, but confusing error message is due to auto-import feature in vscode or some plugin.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me, been going over it this morning and it turns out I was doing a bad job of indenting the function and if-else statements. 
I've done C programming where the compiler ignores any and all attempts to make things readable and I'm very new to Python so thank you all again, this really helped.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems

1. Your `if` block needs to be indented to be inside the function.
2. Your inputs need to be converted to numeric since you can't do math on string types.

Instead:

```
import math
#The quadratic is luckily solved for all coefficients a,b,c except for a=0: this diqualifies the equation as quadratic. 
#I write the function based on following formula: x=(-b+/-sqrt(b^2-4*a*c))/2a

#Problem #2: These have to be numeric otherwise your math will throw an error. I'm wrapping in `int` as an example
a=int(input("Enter a: "))
b=int(input("Enter b: "))
c=int(input("Enter c: "))

def findmyroots(a,b,c):
    dis=b*b-4*a*c
    sqrtdis=math.sqrt(abs(dis))

    #Problem #1: Indentation. This all needs to be inside the function. 
    if dis>0:
        print("The roots are:")
        print((-b+sqrtdis)/(2*a))
        print((-b-sqrtdis)/(2*a))
    elif dis==0:
        print("The roots are:")
        print((-b)/(2*a))
    else:
        print("Roots are lateral")

if a==0:
    print("Write a real quadratic please..")
else:
    findmyroots(a,b,c)\
```

I don't know if your implementation of the quadratic formula is correct (it's been 20+ years since I had to care about that stuff), but this code will run without error.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Just curious: I thought that Python would recognize the input immediately so that I wouldn't need to declare "int", "dynamic typing"(?) I believe I read somewhere..

Comment: Python is both strongly typed and dynamically typed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328920/is-python-strongly-typed). The `input()` function returns a string: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input