# Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons (Python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://www.hkexnews.hk/")

WebElement elements = 
chrome.findElement(By.xpath,
"//[@id='rbAfter2006']/ul")
```

[image]

WebElement elements = chrome.findElement(By.xpath,"//[@id='rbAfter2006']/ul")

The problem is on above line, it shows error "Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons. I have no idea what is the problem assigning elements on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATED***

> Dynamic typing means that **runtime objects (values) have a type**, as
> opposed to static typing where variables have a type.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328980/3324415)

> Dynamic type checking is the process of verifying the type safety of a
> program at runtime.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#DYNAMIC)

The error message you received does not really help to be honest but this meant that the IDE was not happy with:

`WebElement elements = chrome.findElement(By.xpath,"//[@id='rbAfter2006']/ul")`

but rather wants:

`elements = chrome.findElement(By.xpath, "//[@id='rbAfter2006']/ul")`

Comment: but i don't create any function or class, i just edit my question and post the image. on line 12 , it is the error line.

Comment: @PoLam have you tried removing `WebElement` and just keeping `elements`?

Comment: after remove the WebElement, it works.  I don't understand. but thanks!

Comment: I will update my answer to explain.